# Can someone please explain this circuit? SMPS, Bridge Rectifier, Transformer

Tags: power-supply, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, crt

What do these optional components do?

Schematics: https://crtdatabase.com/crts/jvc/jvc-bm-h1300su

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it is a ‘soft start’ circuit. At startup, C010 charges gently via the bridge rectifier and R001/R060. Once charged, the power supply circuit starts up and the extra transformer winding triggers the SCR D015 which shorts the resistors. The SCR remains triggered until the next power on cycle.

Other common methods of soft-start can be a NTC power thermistor. When cold it has high resistance and limits the initial current. Due to current flowing, it heats up and it’s resistance drops.
Relays can be used in a fashion similar to the SCR to bridge some resistance after a given time.

The main aim is to limit the initial start current due to the main capacitor being discharged.

Comment: Thank You.

1) Would a 800V 20A SCR (BT152-800R) be sufficient in this circuit? 



2) The transformer puts out 4.35v. D011 will drop the voltage by ~0.6V. I can set R003 & R007 to reduce the voltage down to ~700mv, gate forward voltage. Should I use 5k/1k, 50k/10k or 500k/100k resistors?

Comment: R003 would probably be around 120R and R007 1k. Note that a SCR gate is current controlled, not voltage. The above resistances will give around 20mA. 
The manufacturer didn’t think it was necessary to populate the circuit, so why do you want to do it? What is the motivation?

Comment: The B+ sags depending on the screen brightness. Would adding the SCR improve voltage regulation?

Comment: Probably not. I’d suggest checking the more obvious things like the electrolytic capacitors first. C025 strikes me as a suspect. Parallel a new, good quality cap of the same value and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's some form of magnetic flux tuned shunt, it positively reacts to reverse transformer flux producing a shunting to the bridge gnd. the function of the other 2 shunt resistors may be to provide differentiated recovery time,